# How do I bind an ASP.NET Repeater Control to an IList<String>?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I've never had to do this, but I'm binding a repeater to a generic list of Strings, and I'm not sure of the correct syntax.

If I was binding to an IList and myType had a property LayerName I'd use this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptChecks" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <input type="checkbox" id="<%#Eval("LayerName") %>"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How can I do this when I'm only binding to a String which does not have any properties to use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptChecks" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <input type="checkbox" id="<%# Container.DataItem %>"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: +1 bang on right!! It used to be necessary to do it this and a few other variations before ASP.net 2